# Migrate Convolutional2D dim_ordering parameter to Conv2D in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-2

I'm newbie with Tensorflow and Keras, and I'm migrating the following code:

```
Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', dim_ordering='tf', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
```

The interpreter suggest me this code:

```
Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation="relu", name="conv1_1", padding="same", data_format="channels_last")
```

My question is:

Is `dim_ordering='tf'` the same as `data_format="channels_last"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `dim_ordering='tf'` is equal to `data_format="channels_last"`, which is also the default, so most of the times you might simply ignore this parameter.

This site seems to store old Keras documentation pages where you can confirm this: http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.8/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d

Answer (score 0):

For the new api, you'll have to convert `dim_ordering` to `data_format` and the corresponding values are `tf` -> `channels_last` or `th` -> `channels_first`. So

```
# for dim_ordering = 'tf'
data_format =  'channels_last'


# for dim_ordering = 'th'
data_format =  'channels_first'
```